# How to insert string in JSON and sort alphabetically file using shell script

Tags: json, shell, sorting, scripting

let say i have JSON file and i have to insert two new string ccddff-live and ccddff-preview which has to inserted into the below JSON file via shell script and order alphabetically

before inserting

``` {``
    "bbccdd-live": {
      "master_url": "http://master.solar.local:8083/solr/bbccdd-live",
      "poll_interval": "00:01:00"
    },
} ```

After Inserting

`"bbccdd-live": {
      "master_url": "http://master.solar.local:8083/solr/bbccdd-live",
      "poll_interval": "00:01:00"
    },
    "bbccdd-preview": {
      "master_url": "http://master.solar.local:8083/solr/bbccdd-preview",
      "poll_interval": "00:01:00"
    },
    "ccddee-live": {
      "master_url": "http://master.solar.local:8083/solr/ccddee-live",
      "poll_interval": "00:01:00"
    },
    "ccddee-preview": {
      "master_url": "http://master.solar.local:8083/solr/ccddee-preview",
      "poll_interval": "00:01:00"
    }`

Comment: Please do not post code into the comments, rather edit the question and format the code like suggested in the help center, thanks.

Comment: Sorting and order don't really make sense when talking about keys of a json object; they're basically just serialized hash tables. If you want order, use an array

Comment: Also, what you have in your post isn't valid json...

Comment: Why is  "bbccdd-preview" added?

Comment: @Shawn Just for example i have posted only a part of JSON file.